# IntelliJ IDEA, the Libraries added to the Intellij are not automatically updating pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In intelliJ IDEA, 
I add libraries dependencies in

1. pom.xml
2. and "Project Structure -> Project Settings -> libraries  -> add ->from maven"

but now, how to write the '2' dependencies to pom.xml automatically?
because there aren't '2' libraries dependency in pom.xml. they aren't synchronization.

I already set Settings > Maven > Importing > Import maven project automatically, Don't work.

note: I want to the Libraries added in the Intellij which can automatically updating pom.xml file.

Comment: You're using it wrong. Close your project and reimport from the pom -- do not add any libraries manually to your project. Do not use the Project-Structure menus you describe above. From now on, always edit your pom.xml by hand and add libraries there (intellij can help with this), then reimport your project to make intellij download the library and add it to your project in the appropriate way. Maven is your library manager in this model, not intellij.

Answer (score 0):

In settings / Maven, you can switch to "import maven project automatically".
Then, when you modify a pom.xml, it will update your project (ie download new dependencies) automatically

Comment: I already set Settings > Maven > Importing > Import maven project automatically, Don't work.  and your don't understand my question, I want to the Libraries added in the Intellij are not automatically updating pom.xml file.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think pom.xml is something which will automatically generate dependencies, If so there wont be any point to maven build type itslef.

Comment: I want to the Libraries added in the Intellij which can automatically updating pom.xml file.

Comment: Updating pom.xml is a manual process, libraries will be added dynamically once updated in pom.xml.